# Flex: Can't monitor app while stepping through code

Tags: apache-flex, debugging

It would be very beneficial to me to be able to monitor my app while stepping through code so that I could pinpoint what step was causing something on the screen to happen. However whenever I am stepping through code the browser just looks blank white. Does anyone know if there is a way to view your application as you step through code? I am using Firefox if that matters.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the debug version of the Flash player installed on your system (it could have been overwritten/corrupted). Are you using Flex Builder?

Comment: I am using Flex Builder 3 pro. I am not sure if I am using the debugging version of flash player tho, how can I check/install?

Comment: Download it from here <http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html>. Normally, this is installed by FB3.

Comment: I went to http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html#fp9 and re-installed it, same thing though, firefox is just a white screen while stepping through code. Is it not like this for you? what browser are you using? Thanks

Comment: I use FF3 and I have not have had a problem. Are you making any http requests etc? Then wait for a while. Check if you have a initialize event handler and if you can get there.

Comment: I am loading XML, thats my only request, everything works fine as I am stepping through code, and as soon as I hit the "resume" button (F8) the app stops being just white and everything is back to normal, FF is just white (not responding) while I am stepping through code. Until now I thought it was like that for everyone.

Comment: *everything works fine as I am stepping through code -- Code executing wise I mean, the screen is just white.

Comment: Ohh ok, thanks, that sucks though, I would like to be able to visually see the app so I can easily tell at what step something on the screen is happening at.

Answer (score 0):

...that's how it works.  You may want to check out [KapInspect](http://labs.kapit.fr/display/kapinspect/Kap+Inspect) for some debugging support while still viewing the app.